# How do I know where my WAV data starts in a WAV file so that I can read the XML before it?

Tags: c#, wav

I have some WAV audio files from a dictaphone that have a little special format. The files have a header containing XML data indicating the start and stop time of the file. I have tried to use XmlReader but its one line of data in the beginning of the file and then I get an error.

```
RIFF .. one line of binary data ..

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

<FileData>
  <StartTime>2019-09-16 15:27:35</StartTime>
  <StopTime>2019-09-16 15:28:32</StopTime>
</FileData>

...audio data ...
```

I am building a small program that will be able to read the XML data from the file header and then sort out the start time and make it a string that I can use as a value in the program. I will, for example, later in the program rename the file to the start time. The files are, as I said, WAV but with this special XML data added first in the file.

Comment: You need to know the terminator for your XML section. StackOverflow generally prefers you show what you have done and ask specific questions regarding your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Your [WAV data](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) should start with the bytes `0x52 0x49 0x46 0x46` (`"RIFF"`).  So start by reading the file and looking for a `0xA` OR `0xD` followed by the 4 bytes above.  That should be the start of your WAV data.  According to your description, everything preceeding the start of the WAV data should be an XML string.  You can read that and load it into an `XmlDocument` or `XmlReader` - whichever API works best for you.

Comment: Thanx, I will try some more